# Typewriter JS - .typeString not working properly

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I used a small framework called Typewriter JS. My guess is that the typewriter var is inaccessible from the eventlistener but I can't figure out why and how to fix it.

```js
var app = document.getElementById('app');

var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.key=="Enter") {
        typewriter.typeString('this does not work');
        console.log("but this works");
    }
});

typewriter.start();
typewriter.typeString('this works');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@latest/dist/core.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: There's no problem accessing the variable. If you put `console.log(Object.keys(typewriter))` in the event listener it works.

Comment: It’s not inaccessible, but another `typewriter.typeString` call after the initial ones are _finished_ doesn’t seem to do anything. Read the documentation of Typewriter.js.

Comment: Typewriter.js is not a framework, it's just a plugin widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop it and start it each time:

```js
var app = document.getElementById('app');

var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.key == "Enter") {
    typewriter.stop();
    typewriter.typeString('this does not work');
    typewriter.start();
    console.log("but this works");
  }
});

typewriter.start();
typewriter.typeString('this works');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@latest/dist/core.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: …and notice what happens (in the original example) when you press enter while "*this works*" is still being typed out